# transform broadcaster for multiple senors

Tags: navigation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm a new user to ros navigation stack. I've a kurt2 robot to work on with 6 super sonic sensors and 8 infrared sensors on it. I'd as per the tutorial in navigation if I've 1 sensor the code as per the tutorial.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_tf_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Rate r(100);
  tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;
  while(n.ok()){
    broadcaster.sendTransform(
      tf::StampedTransform(
        tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(0.1, 0.0, 0.2)),
        ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "base_laser"));
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

How about my case with 6 Sonar n 8 IR sensors? Please let me know

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66783/transform-broadcaster-for-multiple-senors/) by [kiranadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/4433/kiranadam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best solution would be to use a [urdf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf) and the [robot state publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher)

[Watch me ramble on the subject here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-08**:
Oooh! I like this =) (I'm leaving my answer as it has a lower threshold to get working, but this is far superior)